# How to show that this equation is equal.

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{\frac{ 1 }{x+h}- \frac{1}{x}}{h} = \frac{-1}{x(x+h)}$$

That is the equation, if it doesn't load properly then this link http://www.searchonmath.com/ will allow you to see the equation. I'm not sure how I should work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x}}{h} = \frac{\frac{-h}{x(x+h)}}{h}=\frac{-h}{h\cdot x(x+h))}=\frac{-1}{x(x+h)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $x(x+h)$.

$$\frac{\frac{ 1 }{x+h}- \frac{1}{x}}{h} \cdot \frac{x(x + h)}{x(x + h)} = \dfrac {x - (x + h)}{h\cdot x(x + h)} = \frac{-h}{h\cdot x(x + h)} = -\frac 1{x(x+h)}$$

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

1) multiply both sides by $h$.

2)rewrite LHS as $\frac{-h}{x(x+h)}$

LHS=RHS